# Achartengine zoom, pan and onClick events not working correctly after changing chart,

Tags: android, zooming, onclicklistener, achartengine, pan

I am using achartengine to display charts in an Android app.
The app allows the user to display different datasets and different charts types depending on the selections they make from spinners. 
My problem is this. The original chart displays correctly and all zoom, pan, and onClick events preform as expected. But when I remove the first chart and add another, the charts will not zoom or pan from touch and onClick  will not return selected point data. The achartengine zoom and reset buttons still display and work as expected. To remove a chart and add another I have used different variations of the following code with the same results.

```
private void repaint() {
    mchart1_LL_pie = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.chart1_LL_pie);
    if (mChart1_ChartView_pie != null) {
        mchart1_LL_pie.removeView(mChart1_ChartView_pie);
    }

    mChart1_ChartView_pie = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getApplicationContext(), mChart1_Pie_Series, mChart1_Pie_Renderer);

    mchart1_LL_pie.addView(mChart1_ChartView_pie, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

I have also tried to remove all the renderers and clear the data series with the following code.

```
mChart1_Pie_Renderer.removeAllRenderers();
    int size = mChart1_Pie_Series.getItemCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mChart1_Pie_Series.remove(0);
```

And then display the chart with a rebuilt dataset and renderer using the following.

```
mChart1_ChartView_pie = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getApplicationContext(), mChart1_Pie_Series, mChart1_Pie_Renderer);
```

The problem with this approach is that the next chart is not displayed until the display is touched. After the display is touched, the correct chart is displayed and all zoom, pan and onClick events work properly.

Has anyone experienced this problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
Don

Answer (score 0):

I am doing an application with charts. I have an evolution chart with TimeSeries. I paste my function to draw the chart. It can help you :)

```
public void drawChart() {
    mChartView = null;
    mDataset = null;
    mRenderer = null;
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(7);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(220, 220, 220));
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    // mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
    // mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setYTitle(Config.getResource("PRICE") + "("
            + dto.getCurrencyCode() + ")");
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 0, 60, 50, 0 });
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    // mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    evolutionSecurity = new TimeSeries("");
    mDataset.addSeries(evolutionSecurity);

    fillDataEvolution(); //Get data into serie 

    mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
            "dd-MM-yy");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphe_evolution_rate_currency);
    layout.addView(mChartView);

    if (layout != null)
        layout.removeAllViews();

    layout.addView(mChartView);
    mChartView.repaint();
    mChartView = null;


}
```

Then when i select an another value in my spinner i call this method and the chart is redrawn correctly.